# Facebook cURL posting as me?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

Create facebook app

Using a cURL to post a message from an App but it's appearing to be posted from me? How can I can it to post from the app, here's my cURL

```
    $attachment =  array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'message' => '$message',
    'name' => '$name',
    'link' => '$link',
    'description' => '$description',
    'picture'=> '$picture',
    'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => '$name2','link' => '$link2'))
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$pId.'/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

The post works, but it just appears as if I posted it and not the App, suggestions?!

Comment: How did you get the `$token`? And what id is `$pId`?

Comment: token i have saved in a db and pId is the facebook person id

Comment: And the token you've saved is for the particular user, I suppose? I'm not surprised that this posts to the user's feed on behalf of the user, but I don't know how (or whether it's possible to) post as the app.

Comment: Dumb question: Did you check your app settings within FB to make sure all the fields are filled correctly?

Comment: Why are you using curl and not the php sdk? The sdk adds some extra parameters to the post request, parameters like the used sdk, some others and what should interest you the api_key and app_id (which are the same). Try to add those as well.

Comment: The reason I am using curl and not the php sdk is because I'm hitting this from a cron job and need to have it auto post- does that make sense or am i approaching this wrong?

Comment: Token is for that user yes.
@cpilko, yes I have- thanks!

Comment: First , did you try to add the "api_key" and "app_id" parameters? As for cron, the problem is to get access tokens, you will need to manually get a token and save it for the cron every 60 days (if you're using a server side auth, which is the best scenario for this case)

Comment: Wait, I might of misunderstood you, what are you trying to do? What do you mean by "posting as the application"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code it works for me

```
$file = 'image.jpg';
$args = array(
   'message' => 'Photo from application',
    'access_token'=>urlencode('Your Access token'),
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@'.realpath($file);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

May be it helps you.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I am an idiot. I'm sure your code works, mine works fine as well- I just forgot that I created the App under my Facebook as opposed to the App's Facebook which is why it was posting as me. Sorry for being stupid! I guess I should sleep more haha