# (#120) Invalid album id thrown sometimes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

During uploading photos via PHP-SDK API, i had thrown exception: **(#120) Invalid album id**. Everything seems to be ok, album_id is correct. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Is it bug from Facebook?

Comment: Write your code so we can understand.

Comment: Ok here is my code: http://wklej.org/hash/c09e28c41bc/

As i wrote above, everything seems to be ok

Comment: Can you try my code, i add some link of my answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the steps required,

1. User should be a page admin.
2. User should grant 'manage_pages' permission to the app.
3. App should call graph/me/accounts and iterate available accounts to
   get access_token for the page.
4. You proceed to '/album_object_id/photos' with upload.

error message you get is obviously misleading or you use the access token is static maybe,so to get [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Check out some links,

[uploaded photo post to facebook album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726551/uploaded-photo-post-to-facebook-album/14726580#14726580)

[photo not upload to facebook album using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536021/photo-not-upload-to-facebook-album-using-graph-api/14726787#14726787)

[Facebook cURL posting as me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506060/facebook-curl-posting-as-me/10514420#10514420)

May be this help you.

Comment: I think my access token is correct, although i have generated it once for app which i'm using. It has been working correctly for one year. At last time It has been cracking.

Comment: @JarosławMiazga access token changed automatically & its changed every time.

Comment: @JarosławMiazga can you give me your access token to test?

Comment: Huh, you've right. I forgot that at account i have appended new page, but i forgot to change array order, due to get access token :) My problem is solved. Appreciate your help!

Comment: where can I set 2. 'manage pages' permission? I can post to page photos with my user but not to a specific album.